# How to properly set the order in which items are focused when using the tab key

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I'm working on a chat web application. I want to make sure it is accessible for everyone. Currently, when I tab to the chat content, the focus goes to the first message in the chat - which is at the top of the screen. To access the most recent messages, the user must tab through all the messages. Is there a way to override this behavior so tabbing starts at the bottom of the screen? I can't modify the order of elements in the DOM because that will display the messages out of order and confuse users who don't use a screenreader. Besides, the user would still need to tab through all of the messages to access the input to send a message. How can I make sure tabbing doesn't scroll to the top of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bad answer

You could use positive tabindex values, but it's a bad practice.
Many explanations exist about why it's bad. **Don't use tabindex**.

#### Simple answer

People who frequently use tab to navigate usually also know that they can move backwards with shift+tab.
So you are safe if you do nothing special, and just assume  they will be smart enough to navigate backwards in order to quickly reach last messages.

#### Better answer

Ask yourself this question: do each messages really has to be individually focusable ?

Probably the answer is no, or at least not so directly with tab alone.

For your particular case, I suggest you to make a list box instead of a flat serie of messages.
Ideally you should probably have this kind of behavior:

- Pressing tab goes into the list, pressing tab again goes to the next element outside of it.
- Since a single tab is sufficient to skip all messages, the input field to say something can be reached with only two or three tabs
- If I want to read the messages one by one, I go to the list, and then can use arrow keys and home/end to navigate between messages in the list. Pay attention to home/end, they are often forgotten, and arrows aren't sufficient in very talky rooms.
- When going outside of the list and then back in, the same message should be again focused as when leaving the list

In fact, something often forgotten is that keyboard navigation isn't just about tab. There are as well arrow keys, home/end, spacebar and enter, etc.
There are well written advices on what should do what in which situation on the Internet. Search for example "WAI authoring practice".

IN general, the most useful and most frequent used elements  must be quickly reachable.
Keep in mind that if you must press many keys to reach something, you have probably failed in making a well designed interface.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tabindex attribute :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `tabindex` number attribute on specific elements. The incremental order of the `tabindex` will be the selecting order.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Comment: If I use tab index one one element, I have to set it on all the rest. Also, I’ve heard this is a bad practice